# Bivariate basis functions with span invariant to rotation about $z$-axis

Tags: least-squares, polynomial, bivariate, invariance, basis-function

Consider the following functions defined over $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

- $f_0(x,y)=1$
- $f_1(x,y)=x$
- $f_2(x,y)=y$

These functions form a basis with three-dimensional span (the set of all non-vertical planes)

$$f\in\{(x,y)\mapsto ax+by+c|a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

---

If we rotate the coordinate system about the $z$-axis by $\theta$, defining $$g(x,y)=f(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,y\cos\theta+x\sin\theta)$$ we still have the same span

$$g\in\{(x,y)\mapsto Ax+By+c|A=a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta,B=b\cos\theta-a\sin\theta,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

That is to say, any (non-vertical) plane, rotated about the $z$-axis, remains a (non-vertical) plane.

---

I think the same can be said for the basis $\{1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2\}$ (A paraboloid rotated about the $z$-axis is still a paraboloid.)

And for the basis $\{1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3\}$

etc. for higher order bivariate polynomials.

---

Can we design other non-trivial bivariate bases to have this property of "rotational invariance"? (By non-trivial, I mean not consisting of basis functions of only the form $h(x,y)=q(x^2+y^2)$, but something that can potentially be used practically to get a linear-least-squares fit on some arbitrary input function.)

Comment: This is a huge subject: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory.  Your particular application can be framed as characterizing the finite-dimensional real representations of the orthogonal group of the plane within the polynomial algebra.

Comment: @whuber I understand nothing on that page, but thanks anyway. I wonder how is it that the polynomial examples came so easily but I can't for the life of me think of any other examples. What is it, geometrically, about "$i+j\le N$" polynomials that makes them so special?

Comment: They form a graded algebra.  That's a fancy-sounding concept that at heart is quite simple: although there are infinitely many monomials, linear transformations of $(x,y)$ induce linear transformations among monomials of the same degree.  This allows us to analyze an infinite-dimensional vector space into a stack of finite-dimensional ones, which is a great simplification.  If you're curious, the mathematical concept is the same one underlying the quantum theory of atoms and the analysis of electron orbitals into s, p, d, f, ..., shells.

Comment: @whuber I had this vague suspicion that such a "rotationally invariant" basis for a function supported on a circular disk may be composed (up to a desired bandwidth) of the standing wave/resonant modes of a circular drum. Now you mention electron orbitals... Was I onto something?

Comment: @whuber These: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane#Animations_of_several_vibration_modes

Comment: Why not sines and cosines, the real space expression of the basis functions for Fourier transforms?

Comment: @Carl Yes indeed, and I suppose resonant modes of the wave equation in *any* axisymmetric domain ($x^2+y^2<R^2$) would have this property? And perhaps eigenfunctions of the laplacian $\nabla^2$ (heat equation) too?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what is being spanned. Basis functions are useful to span spaces, and the properties of the space itself determines how spanning basis function are usefully defined.